# show/hide a menu item based on specific user role

Tags: 8, navigation

I have a certain number of main menus which need to showcased based on logged in user role. 
for example user with the role, A can sees few menus and user with the role B, sees another set of few menus.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using the routes to manage the permissions. Take the following example:

**mymodule.routing.yml**

```
mymodule.home:
  path: '/mymodule'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::overview'
    _title: 'My Module'
  requirements:
    _role: 'authenticated user'

mymodule.settings:
 path: '/admin/mymodule'
 defaults:
   _form: 'Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyModuleSettingsForm'
   _title: 'Settings'
 requirements:
   _permission: 'administer mymodule'

mymodule.view:
 path: '/mymodule/view'
 defaults:
   _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController::view'
   _title: 'View'
 requirements:
   _role: 'authenticated user'

mymodule.edit:
 path: '/mymodule/edit'
 defaults:
   _form: 'Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyModuleEditForm'
   _title: 'Edit'
 requirements:
   _permission: 'edit mymodule'
```

**mymodule.links.menu.yml**

```
mymodule.home:
  title: 'My Module'
  parent: main
  route_name: mymodule.home
  weight: 10

mymodule.settings:
  title: 'Settings'
  parent: mymodule.home
  route_name: mymodule.settings
  weight: 10

mymodule.view:
  title: 'View'
  parent: mymodule.home
  route_name: mymodule.view
  weight: 10

mymodule.edit:
  title: 'Edit'
  parent: mymodule.home
  route_name: mymodule.edit
  weight: 10
```

With this approach you can display the same menu to all users, but because the links take the permissions from the routes, only users with the `administer mymodule` permission will be able to see the Settings link for example. You can use roles to manage it as well by using `_role: '$rid'`.

Comment: You can also combine roles with `,` and `+`. One means or and the other and. I don't recall which is which.

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 8, you can also use the following code in your `funky.module` file for a programmatic approach. The approach below allows to have access rules independent of menu visibility:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_menu().
 *
 * @param array[] $variables
 */
function funky_preprocess_menu(&$variables) {
  if (in_array('role_b', Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles())) {
    // Hide the menu item
    unset($variables['items']['the_key_you_used_in_your_menu_links_yml_file']);
  }
}
```

This assumes your module is called `funky`. It also assumes you have a `funky.links.menu.yml` file containing something similar to this:

```
the_key_you_used_in_your_menu_links_yml_file:
  title: 'Your menu caption'
  route_name: your_route
  menu_name: account
  cache_contexts:
    - user.roles
```

If you only distinguish if a user has a role or not, then you can further tighten the cache_context by that role. For the example above, `user.roles:role_b` would be appropriate. The documentation for cache contexts is here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-contexts

Comment: Thanks. I was creating a link to an existing route (defined by a core module) for users with a certain role, I didn't want that link to be visible for Administrators or other roles. This worked perfectly.

Comment: I had to configure menus based on groups on our LDAP server, so this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** A [solution using route permissions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/230029/27710) is the best and appropriate solution to avoid repetition and prevent a user to access/view the page using a direct link.

---

All you gotta do is configure your menu block

[image]

Then under Visibility > Roles, check mark ☑ the roles that you want to be able to view this block menu.

[image]

Comment: @Nossweat to add on more, It needs to be achieved for each menu item in the main menu. Something similar to [menu_per_role](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) in D7.

Comment: @Sidhees Well, that module isn't going to port itself. I don't think there is anything similar out there for D8, so better start rolling-up the sleeves. Your need is quite a specific and picky need if you ask me.

Comment: @NoSssweat, I agree, normally no need for this, because drupal checks by default the permissions. If a role has no access to the menu item it is not displayed.

Comment: This will still not solve the problem if one wants to make the link to "/user" depending on the role, either show the menu item or not, and label the menu item "role 1 thing" and another role "role 2 thing"

Comment: this answer acts on the whole menu, while question is about a single menu item  of a menu

Comment: @augusto agreed, at the time I wrote this answer, I wasn't as savvy with D8 and its code. A solution using route permissions is the better option to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-coding approach, the contrib module [Menu Per Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_per_role) may be of use.

> This module allows you to restrict access to menu items based on user roles. Just activate the module and edit a menu item as usual. There will be a new fieldset that allows you to restrict access by role.

Answer (score -1):

Just use [Menu Item Role Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_role_access). It makes it much easier than writing code.

Comment: That module has a years old unresolved issue saying that uninstalling it results in sql errors site wide so I would proceed with caution.